# Override regional settings on Fastreports

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10.3-rio

Do you know if there is a global configuration to set the regional settings used by FastReports ? (FastReports ignores the settings defined on SysUtils FormatSettings).

It's for a corporate application where everything printed should come with the exact same format.

Thank you.

Comment: Try digging in the FastReport's source code or, better, ask to their support

Comment: Thanks @Fabrizio, I have opened a ticked at FastReports support. I will share their answer.

Comment: Looks like FastReports is using the System.Variants.VarToWideStr, which ignores the FormatSettings definition.

Comment: Solved by Peter Wolf here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100960/change-the-regional-settings-format-for-sysem-variants-vartowidestr