# Change the regional settings format for Sysem.Variants.VarToWideStr

Tags: delphi, date-formatting, delphi-10.1-berlin

A third party component (FastReports) on my application is using extensively the System.Variants.VarToWideStr function, which is fine except that it ignores the regional settings I need that application to use.

Example:

```
FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
ShowMessage(VarToWideStr(Date));
FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy/mm/dd';
ShowMessage(VarToWideStr(Date));
```

This code always returns the same string, ignoring the regional settings that I indicate the application to use.

Do you know of another way to change the regional settings that the application (concretely VarToWideStr) is going to use ?.

Comment: Which version of Delphi?  How is Date declared? VarDate or TDateTime? Is there and overloaded version of VarToWideStr that has a second TFormtaSettings parameter?

Comment: Hi @nolaspeaker. It's Delphi 10.1 (it's in the tags) and Date is the SysUtils function, so a TDateTime. No, VarToWideStr doesn't have an overloaded version, and I wouldn't be able to use it anyway because those calls are not in my code but on a third-party component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're screwed by awful design of Variants unit as well as FastReport. `VarToWideStr` calls `VarToWideStrDef` which invokes implicit `_VarToWStr`, then `DateToWStrViaOS` and finally `VarBStrFromDate` from unit `System.VarUtils`.

In fact `VarBStrFromDate` is a reference to function and its implementation depends on compiler. On Windows 32/64 this is just a reference to [VarBstrFromDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varbstrfromdate) from `oleaut32.dll`. Non-Windows compilers fall back to converting the value via `DateTimeToStr` (single argument invariant) which uses global format settings and ['C' format specifier](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.DateTimeToString) to format the value.

There is no good way around that, because all those routines depend too much on global state. Luckily (??) you can point `VarBStrFromDate` to your own implementation. You can get inspired by default implementation for non-Windows platforms seen in function `BackupVarBStrFromDate` of unit `System.VarUtils`. Then you can do something like this:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.VarUtils, System.DateUtils;

function MyVarBstrFromDate(dateIn: TDateTime; LCID: Integer; dwFlags: Integer;
  out bstrOut: WideString): HRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if LCID = VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT then
  begin
    bstrOut := DateTimeToStr(dateIn);
    Result := VAR_OK;
  end
  else
    Result := VAR_NOTIMPL;
end;

{ ... }

System.VarUtils.VarBstrFromDate := MyVarBstrFromDate;
FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-mm-dd';
FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';
Writeln(VarToWideStr(EncodeDate(2019, 11, 29)));
Writeln(VarToWideStr(EncodeDateTime(2019, 11, 29, 10, 30, 50, 700)));
```

to get the result:

> 2019-11-29
>   2019-11-29 10:30:50

You need to be aware that this changes the behavior of all routines that rely on `VarBstrFromDate` throughout the entire application.

The same goes for `VarToStr`. See also [here](https://support.embarcadero.com/article/35913), where the author suggest extracting the date value from variant before conversion to string.

Comment: Thanks Peter, at first view seems to work like a charm.